# Python Dict -> List Manpulation

Tags: python

How can I transform between these data structures formats in Python?

FROM) Dict[str:array[int]]

for example:
{'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]

TO)  Array[Dict[str:int]]

for example:
[{'A':1,'B',4},{'A':2,'B':5},{'A':3,'B':6}]

I have tried comprehension and loop approaches. I seem to only get an array containing the last items, so I am overwriting each result.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: There may be a few steps to it. Just come up with a plan of how you'd do it by hand, then recreate each step, TESTING each step as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will be helpful, but be careful, your arrays in dictionary should always have the same size:

```
D = {'A' : [1, 2, 3], 'B' : [4, 5, 6]}

def transform(dictionary):
    answer = []
    if not dictionary:
        return answer
    pairs = list(dictionary.items())

    for i in range(len(pairs[0][1])):
        cur_dict = {}
        for j in range(len(pairs)):
            cur_dict[pairs[j][0]] = pairs[j][1][i]
        answer.append(cur_dict)
    return answer

print(transform(D))
```

The output:

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 4}, {'A': 2, 'B': 5}, {'A': 3, 'B': 6}]
```